# How many insured vehicles can I have in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I just got a nice 2nd car but I'm not sure what happens if I insure that car along with my other one, do both of them get stay insured or do I lose my previous car insurance?

Comment: I have no evidence to back me up, but just from playing I believe you can insure every car you own.

Comment: I heard some POEPLE say R* might extend the amount of cars you can have like now you can have up to 10 insured cars.they might get it up to 20

Answer (score 5):

In order to insure more cars, you need a garage. If you have a full garage, and you try to insure a new car, it asks you which car you want to get rid of.

If you have no garage the most recent car you insured is your only personal vehicle, which sounds like it would be the case for you if you insure the second vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

You can have up to ten insured cars depending on what size your garage is.

2 car garage= 2 insured cars.  6 car garage = 6 insured cars and 10= car garage 10 insured cars.